# python logging module skip some logs, not writing to file

Tags: python, flask, python-logging

Python logging module sometime skip some logs, not writing to file, here is my config file:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=logfile,logconsole

[formatters]
keys=main

[handler_logfile]
class=logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
formatter=main
args=('logs/my.log', 'midnight')

[handler_logconsole]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=main
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_main]
format=[%(asctime)s] - %(levelname)-8s - %(name)-12s - %(message)s
class=logging.Formatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=logfile,logconsole
```

I have a log when user checkout successfully from my website:

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
.
.
.
log.debug('checkout success: %s', str(order_id))
```

When I check my log files, there some log lines are missing, for example (missing log for 5th order):

```
[2020-06-08 06:32:53,532] - DEBUG - myproject.view.root - checkout success: 3
[2020-06-08 06:32:53,532] - DEBUG - myproject.view.root - checkout success: 4
[2020-06-08 06:32:53,532] - DEBUG - myproject.view.root - checkout success: 6
[2020-06-08 06:32:53,532] - DEBUG - myproject.view.root - checkout success: 7
```

Comment: Check using a debugging or print() if it's reaching that code. Maybe there is an error in your code and it does not reach that line.

Comment: what if 5th order wasn't ordered - so there was nothing to write in log? OR what if there was error and it couldn't write it ?

Comment: @capek code is to that line, because I have order on my database

Comment: @furas 5th order is ordered, beacuse I save orders in database, after saving I have this log line, 100% I'm sure that there is no any error,

Comment: it has to be some problem/error which blocks logging to save it. You could use `try/except` which use `log` (or normal file) to save information.